# Porque no funciona line-height? CSS

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de achicar el espacio entre linea que tiene mi texto, pero no puedo hacer que funcione el line-height. ya intente ponerlo dentro del div, y luego trate de llamar a .text-presentation h1 .text-presentation y ponerlo dentro de tal, pero no responde de ninguna manera

```css
div {
  background-color: rgb(192, 118, 118); /*GRIS*/
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 250px;
}

.text-presentation,
h1,
.button-presentation {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 4px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 90px;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="text-presentation" style="font-size:30px;">Hi! i'm</p>
  <h1 style="font-size:60px;">Sol Gonzalez</h1>
  <p class="text-presentation" style="font-size:20px;">Web Devoloper junior, foodie and biker</p>
  <a href="#proyect">
    <p class="button-presentation" style="font-size:25px;">Check out my work</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que modificar el **Height** de tus elementos **.text-presentation, h1, .button-presentation**, con eso modificas la altura entre elementos y por consiguiente la separación entre ellos según el contenido. El *line.height* es el interlineado de un párrafo, y este sera observado cuando se contiene mucho texto, no sirve para separar elementos independientes HTML.

```css
div {
  background-color: rgb(192, 118, 118); /*GRIS*/
  width: 600px;
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 250px;
}

.text-presentation,
h1,
.button-presentation {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 4px;
  width: 900px;
  /*CON EL HEIGHT CONTROLAS LA ALTURA DE LOS ELEMENTOS*/
  height: 30px;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="text-presentation" style="font-size:30px;">Hi! i'm</p>
  <h1 style="font-size:60px;">Sol Gonzalez</h1>
  <p class="text-presentation" style="font-size:20px;">Web Devoloper junior, foodie and biker</p>
  <a href="#proyect">
    <p class="button-presentation" style="font-size:25px;">Check out my work</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Dime si era eso.

Comment: Siii muchas gracias! estaba tan pendiente de hacer funcionar el line-height que ni tome en consideracion cambiar el height. Tiene sentido que line-heigth solo funcione cuando hay muchas lineas de parrafo. Muchas gracias!